# StructureMap has Profiles what's the equivalent in Autofac?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac, structuremap

Does Autofac have anything similar to StructureMap's Profiles

```cs
IContainer container = new Container(registry =>
{
    registry.Profile("something", p =>
    {
        p.For<IWidget>().Use<AWidget>();
        p.For<Rule>().Use<DefaultRule>();
    });
});
```

Comment: could you briefly explain what profiles do?

Comment: Profiles allow the structure of the object graphs to change based on runtime conditions (the profile name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [StructureMap documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/profiles-and-child-containers/)

> *Profiles* are just named child containers that may be configured upfront through Registry configurations.

You can have the same behavior in *Autofac* when creating a child lifetime scope.

```
using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(childBuilder =>
{
    childBuilder.RegisterType<AWidget>().As<IWidget>();
    childBuilder.RegisterType<DefaultRule>().As<Rule>();
}))
{
    // do things
}
```

if you want to name it, you can use a tag, which is an object and not only a string.

```
using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("something", childBuilder =>
{
    childBuilder.RegisterType<AWidget>().As<IWidget>();
    childBuilder.RegisterType<DefaultRule>().As<Rule>();
}))
{
    // do things
}
```

And if you want to have an equivalence of the `GetProfile` method, you can use this code sample :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()
            .BeginLifetimeScope("A", _ =>
            {
                _.RegisterType<FooA>().As<IFoo>();
            }))
        .Named<ILifetimeScope>("A");

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>()
            .BeginLifetimeScope("B", _ =>
            {
                _.RegisterType<FooB>().As<IFoo>();
            }))
        .Named<ILifetimeScope>("B");

// build the root of all profile
IContainer container = builder.Build();

// get the profile lifetimescope 
ILifetimeScope profileScope = container.ResolveNamed<ILifetimeScope>("B");

// use a working lifetimescope from your profile
using (ILifetimeScope workingScope = profileScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    IFoo foo = workingScope.Resolve<IFoo>();
    Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType());
}
```

By the way, be careful on not using this code like a [service locator anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: Hi Cyril, I believe there is a difference between Child and Nested containers within StructureMap as stated in the documentation -> Child Containers are not interchangeable with Nested Containers. See Nested Containers (Per Request/Transaction) for more information on nested containers.

Comment: However re-registering with a new LifetimeScope should work. Thanks for your feedback!